# Variable interference with threads

Tags: java, java-me, thread-safety

```
Thread t1= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //perform Database stuff
            }
        });
t1.start();
initCache();//perform other Database stuff (Can this code be executed while thread 1 is running?)
```

How can I make sure the initCache method is forced to wait after t1 finishes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't run it in a different thread to start with?

You *could* call `t1.join()` but really, if you want to run task X and then task Y, just run them in the same thread...

Answer (score 0):

If you want `initCache()` to only run *after* `t1` has finished running, then why do you start `t1` in the first place?

Simply execute the code in `run()` and then `initCache()`.

If there's some other action happening between `t1.start()` and `initCache()`, then you could use `t1.join()` to wait for `t1` to finish before calling `initCache()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using *join()*? Seriously? Did the 90's called because they want their low-level synchronization facilities back?

What about something a bit more high-level? Like a CountDownLatch?

```
final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
Thread t1= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //perform Database stuff
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        });
t1.start();
cdl.await();
initCache();
```

Can also be configured with a timeout etc.

Comment: From my reading of *Effective Java* and *Java Concurrency In Practice* I was under the impression that besides for concurrency API authors there really weren't many valid reasons to use low-level things like *join()* anymore.  I've seen huge multi-threaded Java codebase with exactly zero calls to *join* or *yeld* and other low-level things I don't even remember Java still has.

Comment: If all you want to do is wait for a thread to finish, there's no need to introduce *another* concept into it. What *benefit* is there in introducing the CountDownLatch over just calling `join` *in this particular case*? High level abstractions are great in many cases - but if you're *just* waiting for a thread to finish, I don't see what's wrong with using `join`. Not that there's any evidence the OP needs a separate thread in the first place...

Comment: I understand how `wait()` and `notify()`/`notifyAll()` should be avoided and be replaced by better/more modern alternatives, but I too don't see the problem in using `join()` here. Also: is this the reason for the downvotes?

Comment: @Joachim: I suspect so, yes. I noticed the downvote on my answer 4 minutes after Gugussee had posted his answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (t1.isAlive()) {
  try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep();
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //check again
  }
}
initCache();
```

That should do it. Although actually the `t1.join()` method is a hell of a lot simpler.